# IntentService Not found

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I am getting this exception in the LogCat:

```
Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.thePackage.me/com.thePackage.c2dm.RegistrationService (has extras) }: not found
```

Here is by `IntentService`. Right now for testing I am just issuing a log message

```
public class RegistrationService extends IntentService {

    public RegistrationService(){
        super("NAME");
    }
    public RegistrationService(String name) {
        super(name);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("RegistrationService", "onHandleIntent INVOKED");
        System.out.println(intent.getDataString());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        System.out.println(intent.getDataString());
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

I am starting this service from a `BroadcastReciever` in this manner

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RegistrationService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtra("REG_ID", reg_Id);
serviceIntent.putExtra("DEVICE ID", manager.getDeviceId());
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Why is this exception being generated? Do I have to declare this in the `Manifest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, you have to declare the service in your Manifest file, even if it's not in your application namespace. If, for instance, we want to use the Urban Airship Push service, we have to declare it:

```
<service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" />
```

Comment: what would the `android:name` be for my service?  



`<service android:name="com.thePackage.c2dm.RegistrationService" />`

Comment: Yes, the name is always the fully qualified Java class name, or if the component lives within your own application namespace, a name relative to your application package (e.g. `.services.MyService` is exploded to `com.myapp.services.MyService` if `com.myapp` is your app namespace)